# OpenID Connect Provider in Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I've been searching how to implement an OpenID Connect provider in python and I have found [this library](https://github.com/rohe/pyoidc) made by Roland Hedberg ([it's recommended by OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) ).
But I've read [the docs](http://pyoidc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/op.html), [the examples](https://github.com/rohe/pyoidc/tree/master/oidc_example) and I think it examples are overcomplicated for people that have no big knowledge about it (provider, wsgi and cli are mixed).

So my question is: do anyone knows simpler examples or tutorials to implement this library or should I try to implement my provider on top of an OAuth2 library?

Comment: I think "recommended by OpenID " is to strong a statement. They are merely listing implementations that have been submitted to them.

Answer (score 9):

I've passed this trouble before. Working on top of OAuthlib was a pain (Roland lib was also really hard to understand it), so I decided to start from the ground up.

[django-oidc-provider](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-oidc-provider) can help you providing out of the box all the endpoints, data and logic needed to add OpenID Connect capabilities to your Django projects. Have full support for Python 3 and 2. Also latest versions of django.

View on GitHub: https://github.com/juanifioren/django-oidc-provider

Anything you want to know please ask.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone found this question. I've been working on [Authlib](https://authlib.org/) for a long time, before Authlib I created Flask-OAuthlib. With Authlib v0.6+, you can easily [create an OpenID Connect service in Flask](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/oidc.html) (Django integration is coming).

Here are some resources that you may need:

1. GitHub: https://github.com/lepture/authlib
2. Example on OAuth 2: https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server
3. Documentation on OAuth 2: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/oauth2.html
4. Documentation on OpenID Connect: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/oidc.html

I'll update the answer when an example of oidc available.

Answer (score 0):

Here some updates

Roland oidc provider
https://github.com/IdentityPython/oidc-op
and rp
https://github.com/IdentityPython/JWTConnect-Python-OidcRP

SATOSA (IAM Proxy) oidcop frontend
https://github.com/UniversitaDellaCalabria/SATOSA-oidcop